# Value for `(window-start)` is wrong?

Tags: window

I use the `ace-window` package to move focus from one Emacs window to another.  It uses the built-in function `window-start` to decide where to place an overlay that contains a number I would type to jump to that window. That is, to make that window (and the frame containing it) the focus of input.

Sometimes, a window will not display a number, making me guess how to get to it.

The `window-start` function is supposed to return the character position in the buffer that is the top-left visible position in that window.

It seems that `window-start` sometimes returns the position in that window's buffer that is one line *above* the actual first-displayed position. So, `ace-window` dutifully displays the number in a place that is not visible.

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone have suggestions on how I could fix it?

Speculation: 
- Could it be thrown off by lines with unusual line-height such as those containing special glyphs like `HEAVY CHECK MARK`?
- Could it be caused by unusual fringes or a header-line?
[One buffer where I experienced this, had some lines with extra-tall characters. Another was an `info` buffer that had a header-line.]

Comment: More speculation: Perhaps `window-start` is called before redisplay has updated it? (re: [`(elisp) Window Start and End`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Start-and-End.html))

Comment: Unfortunately, `window-start` and `window-end` can never be 100% entirely accurate even when using the optional argument to latter; i.e., UPDATE.  It is sad, but true ...  Only by going inside the C source code and creating new features that work with redisplay can these values be obtained with 100% accuracy.  Why?  Because redisplay does not know the values 100% of the time until it has finished and there are numerous settings and stuff that affect where the bouncing ball will finally land.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23923371/emacs-calculating-new-window-start-end-without-redisplay

Comment: In order to fix this, I think one would have to first figure out what is happening.  Maybe `window-start` is actually correct (that would be my guess) but the corresponding buffer text is made `invisible` and that ends hiding the overlay as well?

Comment: Please consider filing and Emacs bug/enhancement-request report: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: @Stefan I ran it under edebug and saved the value returned for the relevant window. Then I used `goto-char` and saw that it was the BOL position of the line before what should be the value of `(window-start)`.  It happened for two windows in two distinct frames. That’s why I think the value is wrong.

Comment: @lawlist I don’t believe this is related to redisplay as these are static windows that are only being modified by ` ace-window` trying to put an overlay of a single character. The text of the buffer in the window and the sizes of the windows and frames does not change.

Comment: Does placing the overlay at the prior window-start cause redisplay to move the screen downward one line; e.g., a scrolling of 1 line?  If so, then there we have our answer ... (although not the desired answer).

Comment: @lawlist No. that would be annoying, but preferable to what I have. I want to see 1, 2, 3, …, n so I can tap that number to select the window. Having the window weirdly scroll by one line is better than “guess what number would be in this one!” ;-)

Comment: From what you say, `window-start` seems to return an incorrect answer, so you might want to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.